# Login for users of different positions

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I am sort of new to login feature for projects and am trying to do logins for my group, which consists of 3 users, namely Nurse, Patient and Pharmacist. I think I am about to complete the loin process but I have a problem with one of my methods, getPosition() in my LoginDAO.cs. So far, I have not done any login codes for patient and pharmacist as i will need my group mates' parts for it to work, but shown below is what I have done. Somehow, login(string nric, string pw) works, but not getPosition(string nric). This is the error that i get from my error log:
Exception: Must declare the scalar variable "@paraNRIC". Source: LoginDAO.getPosition
Thanks in advance :D

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    login login = new login();
    login.nric = tbLoginID.Text;
    login.pw = tbPassword.Text;
    if (login.userLogin(login.nric, login.pw))
    {
        if (login.getPosition(login.nric) == "Nurse")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Nurse.aspx");
        }
        else if (login.getPosition(login.nric) == "Patient")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Patient.aspx");
        }
        else if (login.getPosition(login.nric) == "Pharmacist")
        {
            Response.Redirect("PharmacistDisplay.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lblErr.Text = "Invalid account.";
    }
}

public bool login(string nric, string pw)
{
    bool flag = false;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();

    sqlStr.AppendLine("SELECT Password from Position");
    sqlStr.AppendLine("Where NRIC = @paraNRIC");
    try
    {
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr.ToString(), myconn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paraNRIC", nric);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt == null)
        {
            flag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            string dbhashedpw = dt.Rows[0]["Password"].ToString();
            flag = Helper.VerifyHash(pw, "SHA512", dbhashedpw);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("NurseDAO.login", sqlStr.ToString(), exc);
    }


    return flag;
}

public string getPosition(string nric)
{
    string dbPosition = "";
    int result = 0;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();
    sqlStr.AppendLine("SELECT Position from Position ");
    sqlStr.AppendLine("where NRIC = @paraNRIC");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paraNRIC", nric);
    try
    {
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr.ToString(), myconn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        myconn.Open();
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dbPosition = dt.Rows[0]["Position"].ToString();
        myconn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        logManager log = new logManager();
        log.addLog("LoginDAO.getPosition", sqlStr.ToString(), exc);
    }


    return dbPosition;
`}
```

Comment: I am using the sql server database provided by visual studios 2013. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
// lines omitted
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paraNRIC", nric);
try
{
    SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr.ToString(), myconn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
```

Note that you are instantiating `cmd` twice.  The code adds the parameters to the first `SqlCommand` instance, but executes the second instance.

To resolve, ensure you declare the parameters on the instance of SqlCommand you invoke:

```
public string getPosition(string nric)
{
    string dbPosition = "";
    int result = 0;
    // remove this line: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    StringBuilder sqlStr = new StringBuilder();
    sqlStr.AppendLine("SELECT Position from Position ");
    sqlStr.AppendLine("where NRIC = @paraNRIC");
    // move parameter declaration until after you declare cmd
    try
    {
        SqlConnection myconn = new SqlConnection(DBConnect);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr.ToString(), myconn);
        // add the parameters here:
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paraNRIC", nric);
        // code continues
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change this line

sqlStr.AppendLine("where NRIC = @paraNRIC");

To This

sqlStr.AppendLine("where NRIC = '" + nric + "'");

and avoid parameters altogether.

Comment: Hmm... just tried that method, but error log showed up saying "Exception: Invalid column name 'S123455A'. where S123455A is the nric that i entered